# Generics - Confusion

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
public <X> X createData(int n)
{
    int[] values = new int[n];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        values[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, values.length);
    return (X )values;
}
```

Hi there, I have cobbled together a small method to return an int array as a generic type (i think?)

The point of this is, I am to call a users method who is going to generate me some data, at which point I then take that data and invoke a method of their selection.

The issue is, when i call this method how can I convert the generic type to its "proper" type so as it invoke the method with this data.

Typically my process will be

1) invoke the user method to get their data(reflection)

2) use this data to invoke their other method(reflection)

Is what I am doing/trying here possible or in the process of making it a generic return type am i ruining everything?

Thanks

Comment: You ... can't cast like that. You have an `int` array, what could you cast that to? What exactly are you trying to solve here? It's not really what Generics are used for.

Comment: This method doesn't make sense conceptually. It's creating an int[] array, and then trying to cast it to another type? What kind of type would it be casting to?

Comment: yes this is my complete misunderstanding, sorry guys. Essentially i am just messing around because the idea is that the user could want to generate any random data and my method would need to account for that

Comment: Indeed, 'take that data and invoke a method of their selection' - why not pass an implementation of an interface?

Comment: @ricki - an array of `int`s is ... specific. `int` is a primitive, and that's all it can ever be.

Comment: @BrianRoach Ok so how would i make the method adaptable for data of List<Ball> or something ?

Comment: @Ricki - what is the "user's data" that you want to operate on, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: it can be whatever they need it to be. We are creating a type of profiling tool as a uni project for student algorithm measuring. We time their algorithm but to invoke it we may need any type of parameter, we have therfore created an interface the user has to implement that forces them to generate the data they need to run their algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to return a list then I would do it by defining a Supplier interface,

```
public interface Supplier<T> extends Serializable {
    public T get();
}
```

Which can be defined as,

```
public <X> List<X> createData(Supplier<X> datum, Integer length){
    List<X> values = new ArrayList<X>();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        values.add(datum.get());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, values.size());
    return values;
}
```

and can be used as,

```
List<Integer> ints = createData(new Supplier<Integer>() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public Integer get() {
            return rand.nextInt(100);
        }
    }, 10);
```